# Group by then loop

Tags: django

So I have products that I want to loop through display on a Django detail view. The detail view is for a particular truck that will take all the products assigned to it to a city. So all the products on the view are assigned to this particular truck.

The problem is, each product is also assigned to a particular customer. So I want the view to look something like

**Truck 1 detail view**

Customer 1

- Product 1 Product 2 Product 5

Customer 2

- Product 3, Product 4, Produt 6

As a basic example. The real life example may have 20-30 products and 5-6 customers.

Of course I could just do some kind of order by but I want the looping of these to allow me to start new style of formatting whenever there is a new customer (similar to the above format), in order to make it easier to view for the employee who will be loading this truck.

Is this possible? as it's confused me a little bit.

Edit:

My relevant models look something like;

```
class Truck(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()

class Agent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    truck = models.ForeignKey(Truck, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    agent = models.ForeignKey(Agent, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    status = models.IntegerField()
```

Agent = customer. It's worth mentioning that each product is unique specially made per customer - and only has one instance. Once each instance has been sent on a truck to the customer it will receive an updated 'status' and be no longer classed as in stock.

Comment: Can you share your models?

Comment: Sorry. added my models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As queryset, we can filter the `Product`s on a certain `Truck`, and then we can use [**`itertools.groupby`** [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group per `Agent`. Note that what you here display is a *list* (well a collection), so it makes more sense to use a [**`ListView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) here.

```
from app.models import Product
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from itertools import groupby
from operator import attrgetter

class ProductCustomerListView(ListView):

    model = Product

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Product.objects.filter(
            truck_id=self.kwargs['truck_id']
        ).prefetch_related('agent').order_by('agent_id')

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['grouped'] = groupby(context['object_list'], attrgetter('agent'))
        return context
```

where `truck_id` is an URL parameter that specifies the id of the `Truck` for which we want to show the elements grouped per `Agent`.

In the template, we then "unwind" the `groupby`:

```
<ul>
    {% for agent, products in grouped %}
    <li>{{ agent.name }}</li>
    <ul>
    {% for product in products %}
        <li>{{ product.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```